# Regex to find the host name from java

Tags: java, regex

```
class HostName{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String url = "http://www.example.com:80/path/to/myfile.html?key1=value1&key2=value2";
        Pattern hostname = Pattern.compile(".*www.(.*).com");
        Matcher m1 = hostname.matcher(url);
        System.out.println("hostname: " + "" + m1);
    }
}
```

With this code I'm trying to get the host name from the url, in this case "example".

It compiled successfully but I got this error:

```
hostname: java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=.*www.(.*).com region=0,69 lastmatch=]
```

Please help!

Comment: Fwiw: you might fine-tune your regex a bit. One would probably expect literal dots after the `www` subdomain and before the tld. Also, the host name should probably not be empty. Just to be on the safe side, I'd make the match non-greedy: `".*www\\.(.+?)\\.com")`. Hth.

Comment: The error is likely the `Matcher` object, where there is no default method.

Answer (score 4):

You're printing the string representation of `Matcher`. Use it to match the pattern and get the matched group instead

```
if (m1.find()) {
    System.out.println("hostname: " + m1.group(1));
}
```